# ACF category images doesn't show

Tags: wordpress, image, advanced-custom-fields

I have created ACF image field and added sample image on category and now I want to replace category icon in:

```
$cat_links .=  '<li><a href="' . esc_url($term_url) . '"><img src="' . esc_url($term_icon) . '">';
```

with ACF image field:

```
$cat_links .=  '<li><a href="' . esc_url($term_url) . '"><img src=" <?php the_field($test); ?>"';
```

and don't know what I'm doing wrong ..

Thanks for help,
A

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the label return value is set to `Image URL`. Try this below code.

```
$cat_links .= '<li><img src="<?php the_field('test'); ?>" />';
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tryed scenarios 'the_field('test');' ; 'the_field('$test');' ; 'the_field('{test}');' and 'the_field('{$test}');' and doesn't working

Comment: @alench can you post a picture of your ACF setup?

Comment: here is screen: https://ibb.co/evK0WV   - is maybe problem in return value

Comment: @alench, your return value is set to `Array`. You need to set it to `Image URL`. Once you do that use the code reference I mentioned above and it should work.

Comment: I tryed, but term_ur is not from ACF is plugin and I need to change only picture. If I try with ' $cat_links .= '<li><a href="' . esc_url($term_url) . '">' . '<img src="<?php the_field({test});?>">';' I don't get any errors but image is not showing. I tryed plenty of scenarios (like in first comment) and picture still donesn't showing. In browser inspector code looks like: '<img src="&lt;?php the_field({test});?&gt;" style="">'

Comment: `term_url` is not going to show if it is not a custom field. I included it in the code I provided you because that is what you put in your example. Also, I added the brackets to indicate where you need to put your field name. Remove the brackets. I have added what I think you want in my code above. **Next time please post your own code so we know exactly what you are trying to achieve.**

**ALSO**, as I have been repeatedly been saying, **you need to set the Return Value as `Image URL` inside of your custom field. It is an option when you set it up**. Once you have done this it will work.

Comment: thank you but field was set to image url after first comment when you said me to, but I get error for t_string like a said. I added ACF image in category and now I want to change default category image with tihis image in foreach loop, from github.com/GeoDirectory/supreme-directory/blob/master/inc/… in 845 line

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to change the code. You can set the Image URL in ACF field like this from admin. https://prnt.sc/lap21j

Comment: Hello, I tryed that (https://ibb.co/noMGOA) but I get error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'test' (T_STRING)

Comment: Can you please share the Latest Code which you have used !!

Comment: I tryed to add different category picture (field test) in: ' $cat_links = '<div class="sd-detail-cat-links"><ul>';
                foreach ($cats_arr as $cat) {
                    ....
                    $cat_links .= '<li><img src="<?php the_field('test'); ?>" />';
                    $cat_links .= '<span class="cat-link">' . esc_attr($term_arr->name) . '</span>';
                    $cat_links .= '</a></li>';
                }    
                $cat_links .= '</ul></div> ' and I get error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'test' (T_STRING) ...

Comment: There is a Syntex error in your code. Please use below code.
***************************************************************


$cat_links = '<div class="sd-detail-cat-links"><ul>'; 
  foreach ($cats_arr as $cat) { 
   $cat_links .= '<li><img src="'.the_field('test').'" />'; 
   $cat_links .= '<span class="cat-link">' . esc_attr($term_arr->name) . '</span>'; 
   $cat_links .= '</a></li>'; 
  } 
 $cat_links .= '</ul></div> '

Comment: thanks! I have try but then I get errors from other plugins .. I'll tell you new information soon